# Sprite inside div not showing

Tags: html, css

I want to use sprite image inside the div, where I use multiple `img` tags showing different parts of the same sprite at the same place (sprite is assumed to be transparent png image). I used online sprite generator which produced responsive sprite with css file.

Here is what I've got: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mznmmhcf/4/)

Here is the code itself:

```
<div id="jersey">
    <img style="position:absolute;width:131px;"class="custom-sprite custom-1">
    <img style="position:absolute;width:131px" class="custom-sprite custom-2">
    <img style="position:absolute;width:131px" class="custom-sprite custom-3">
</div>

.custom-sprite {
    max-width: 100%; background-size: 100%; 
    background:url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/44/1f/71/441f7163417c68b66183a46d94451ba0.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.custom-sprite {
    max-width: 100%; background-size: 100%; 
    background:url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/44/1f/71/441f7163417c68b66183a46d94451ba0.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.custom-1 { 
    background-position: 0 0%;
    background-size: 100%; 
}
.custom-2 { 
    background-position: 0 64.606181%;
    background-size: 100%; 
}
.custom-3 {
    background-position: 0 1.595214%;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#jersey {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px; 
}
```

The problem is that it is not showing anything, I want the sprite to change it's size depending on the width of the image containing it.

EDIT 1: sprite image is used as an example

Comment: If you wants to use background images then use them on `<div>`, `<span>` or other similar elements; not on `<img>` itself.

Comment: add fix height width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to point out, you are supposed to use `div` or `span` elements when using the sprites, instead of images, because you are not showing an image, but rather setting a background to an element.

Secondly, you need to specify explicitly the height and width of the sprite element.

Please see the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mznmmhcf/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add image height in your code;

please find update fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mznmmhcf/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="jersey">
    <img style="width:131px; height: 200px;"class="custom-sprite custom-1">
    <img style="width:131px; height: 200px;" class="custom-sprite custom-2">
    <img style="width:131px; height: 200px;" class="custom-sprite custom-3">
</div>
```

**css**

```
.custom-sprite {
    max-width: 100%; background-size: 100%; 
    background:url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/44/1f/71/441f7163417c68b66183a46d94451ba0.jpg) no-repeat;
    float: left;
}

.custom-1 { background-position: 0 0%; background-size: 100%; }
.custom-2 { background-position: 0 64.606181%; background-size: 100%; }
.custom-3 { background-position: 0 1.595214%; background-size: 100%; }

#jersey {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px; 
    width:400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```